# Family of convex functions defined on convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $f^\theta(x)$ be a convex function parametrized by $\theta$ in a convex set $\Theta$.

(toy example to illustrate: $f^\theta(x) = x^2 + \theta$, with $\Theta = [0,1]$.)

In general, is set of functions $\mathcal{F} = \{ f^\theta(\cdot), \theta \in \Theta\}$ convex?

The set $\mathcal{F}$ would be convex iff for any $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$, the "line segment" $tf + (1-t)g$ is in $\mathcal{F}$, for $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Could you please clarify: when you say "$f^\theta(x)$ [is] a convex function parameterized by $\theta$ in a convex set $\Theta$", do you mean that **for every** $\theta \in \Theta$, $f^\theta(x)$ is convex? If so, this seems like a tautology. Otherwise, we could have functions like $f^\theta(x)=x^\theta$ which is convex for $\theta\geq 1$ and nonconvex for $\theta\in\left]0,1\right[$. In this case, $\mathcal{F}$ is nonconvex for, e.g., $\Theta=[0,2]$.

Comment: @Zim I meant the former. Is it obvious that "for every $\theta \in \Theta, f^\theta(x)$ is convex" implies that $\mathcal{F}$ is convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $f^\theta = 1$ for $\theta \in (0,1]$ and $f^0 = 0$. There is no $\theta$ such that $f^\theta = \frac12 (f^0+f^1)$.